# Path to drupal module from inside of javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, drupal-7

Is there a way to get the drupal(7) module path from which the .js was loaded?
I know that JS is a front-end language, but possibly Drupal passes that info in the Drupal object somehow?

Basicly I want to do something like this:

```
$('#selectable_html').load("selectable_html.html");
```

But since Drupal constructs pages on the fly this request transforms to `"http://___/node/add/selectable_html.html"`, which is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass things to Javascript via Drupal using [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) using the 'setting' option.

> Add settings ('setting'): Adds settings to Drupal's global storage of
> JavaScript settings. Per-page settings are required by some modules to
> function properly.
>
> drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('key' => 'value')),
> 'setting');

You could then pass the path returned from [drupal_get_path('module', 'name')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7) and access it in Javascript using Drupal.setting.

> All settings will be accessible at Drupal.settings.